# Socket programming, trying to connect to server freezes the application and pinwheels

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to create a simple chat application in java. Right now I'm having issues connecting to my server. Whenever I open the chat it causes the application to freeze and my mouse turns into a pinwheel. the message window does not open and closing the program on intellij is the only way to stop it.

I tried printing my local port and I'm using the result as my current port so I know that is not the problem. I've been looking at some tutorials online and I don't think my code is the problem but I think I might have some lines misplaced. I tried having them connect in the constructor of each class but that was causing an issue so I tried moving them to methods - still having the same issue.

Client side:

```
public class MessagingSupport {

public MessagingSupport(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;

//        SupportSideMessagingSupport supportSideMessagingSupport = new SupportSideMessagingSupport();
// thought this might be causing the issue but it freezes whether this 
// is commented out
    connect();

}
private void connect(){
    SupportSideMessagingSupport supportSideMessagingSupport = new SupportSideMessagingSupport();
// commenting this out gets a java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) error
    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 56515);
        System.out.println("listening on port: " + socket.getLocalPort());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        while(true){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Client: ");
            String message = sc.nextLine();
            dos.writeUTF(message);

            String res = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server said: " + res);
            if (res.equals("bye")){
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server side

```
public class SupportSideMessagingSupport {

public SupportSideMessagingSupport(){
    connectToServer();
}
private void connectToServer(){
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(56515);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("connected");
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {

            String res = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Client said: " + res);
            if (res.equals("bye")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Server: ");
        String message = sc.nextLine();
        dos.writeUTF(message);
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So right now the code above causes the application to freeze. Instead it should open up a chat in the console log. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `readUTF` is a blocking operation, which means that the application thread can not do anything else until the method returns. To solve it, you either need to call `readUTF` in a new thread, or use the non-blocking java.nio socket API.

Comment: @marstran can you expand on that? I got that from a tutorial and they had no issues with blocking

Comment: Which tutorial? The java.io API is inherently blocking. There's no way around that.

Comment: @marstran It was some youtube video. I closed out of it earlier today. I'm still having no luck. here's my updated code. a lot has changed. https://pastebin.com/SEwsCR56 but I still have the same problem. a connection can't be established and `getLocalPort()` always returns with -1 but the server and client can't connect at that port. thanks for helping